# how to do whenReady for multiple future constructs-scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a multiple futures based construct like this

```
 val future1 = returnsFuture1()
 val future2 = returnsFuture2()
 val future3 = returnsFuture3()
 val future4 = returnsFuture4()
 val future5 = returnsFuture5()
```

how do i do something like this

```
whenReady(future1,future2,future3,future4,future5) 
{
.
.
.
}
```

So what I want is a block to be executed when all of the futures are completed. I am not interested in what comes out of each future here but the result of all the futures having being completed. Nevertheless, I welcome solutions which provides the value out of each individual future for multiple future in whenReady without having to do the dreaded nested constructs.